Construction of general solutions from a particular solution. Ermakov equation.
My question is in particular about the Ermakov equation, but in general it is about the construction of general solutions to ordinary differential equations. This is the first time I see such construction, so apologies if it is too trivial.
The Ermakov equation
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + f(x) y = a y^{-3},
$$
where f(x) is a function of the independent variable $x$ and $a$ is a constant, has as a general solution
$$
C_1 y^2 = a w^2 + w^2\left(C_2 + C_1\int\frac{dx}{w^2} \right)^2,
$$
for $C_1,C_2$ constants. The function $w=w(x)$ is taken as any solution of the homogeneous equation
$$
\frac{d^2w}{dx^2} + f(x) w = 0.
$$
The question: Why any solution $w(x)$ can yield a general solution for $y$? I am not sure this is obvious, or perhaps I misunderstood something. For instance, I can find, say, $w$ real and thus $y$ will be real. However, it may as well be the case that the most general solution for $w$ is complex, and then my previous real solution would generate a "restricted" solution for $y$.

Considering the second order linear ODE
\begin{align}
w''+f(x)w=0,
\end{align}
we will take for granted here that the general solution is
\begin{align}\tag{*}
w=C_1w_1+C_2w_2,
\end{align}
where $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent independent solutions to our ODE. If we eliminate our constants via differentiation we have that
\begin{align}
\left(w/w_1\right)'=C_2\left(w_2/w_1\right)',\quad \text{and}\quad \left(\frac{(w/w_1)'}{(w_2/w_1)'}\right)'=0.
\end{align}
Define the Wronskian $W(x)=w_1w_2'-w_1'w_2$ and simplify our latter expression:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{w_1}{W}w'-\frac{w_1}{W}w\right)'&=\frac{w_1}{W}w''-w_1\frac{W'}{W^2}w'-\left(\frac{w_1}{W}\right)'w=0,\\\\
\implies & w''-\frac{W'}{W}w'-\frac{W}{w_1}\left(\frac{w_1}{W}\right)'w=0.
\end{align}
If (*) is indeed the solution to our ODE it must be true that
\begin{align}
W(x)\equiv W_0\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{w_1''}{w_1}=-f(x),
\end{align}
the latter of which is obviously true if $w_1$ is a solution to our ODE. Since our Wronskian equals a constant, and is a simple first order linear ODE, it can be integrated to find $w_2$ in terms of $w_1$
\begin{align}
w_1w_2'-w_1'w_2=W_0,\quad w_2=w_1(c+W_0\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{w_1^2}).
\end{align}
We take $c=0$ as $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent. We can then write our general solution as
\begin{align}
w=w_1\left(C_1+C_2\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{w_1^2}\right),
\end{align}
which we see in our solution to the Ermakov equation
\begin{align}
C_1y^2=aw_1^2+w_1^2\left(C_1+C_2\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{w_1^2}\right)^2=aw_1^2+w^2.
\end{align}

You can get this solution via the transformation
\begin{align}
\xi=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{w_1^2},\quad z=\frac{y}{w_1}\implies z''_{\xi\xi}=az^{-3},
\end{align}
which is easily integrated twice.

In a very short paper published in 1950, Edmund Pinney wrote that the general solution to the nonlinear differential equation
$$
y''+p(x)y-\frac{a}{y^3}=0 \tag{1}
$$
is
$$
y(x)=\left[u^2(x)+\frac{av^2(x)}{W^2}\right]^{1/2}, \tag{2}
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent solutions to the linear equation
$$
y''+p(x)y=0, \tag{3}
$$
and $W=uv'-u'v$ is their Wronskian.
Now, if $w$ is any (nonzero) solution to Eq. $(3)$, it's a simple exercise to show that
$$
z=w\left(C_2+C_1\int\frac{dx}{w^2}\right) \tag{4}
$$
also is a solution to $(3)$; in addition, $w$ and $z$ are linearly independent if $C_1\neq 0$. It's also a simple exercise to show that the general solution presented in the OP can be rewritten in the form $(2)$ with the identification
$$
u=\sqrt{\frac{a}{C_1}}w, \qquad v=z. \tag{5}
$$
Therefore, to write the general solution $(2)$ to the Ermakov equation $(1)$ one needs two linearly independent solutions to the linear equation $(3)$, but given a nontrivial solution $w$ to the latter, Eq. $(4)$ yields another, linearly independent, solution $z$.
